# Converting Map<T> to derived class

Tags: java

I have the following class:

```
class DerivedMap extends Hashmap<String,Object>
{}
```

Which I use because I want to implement some custom actions for this type of map.

I then pass instances of this class to an external api that wants Map, this naturally works well.

The problem is that I also get Map instances as return values from the api. Since a real object hides behind the interface that the api chose I know I cannot just cast it.

So, how do I convert Map to my custom DerivedMap? Must I manually copy all the keys/values?

Thanks.

Comment: putAll() [and 7 more chars to go]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could create a constructor like this:

```
class DerivedMap extends HashMap<String, Object> {
    public DerivedMap(Map<String, Object> map) {
        super(map);
    }
}
```

and then create a `DerivedMap` from a `Map` like this:

```
derivedMap = new DerivedMap(otherMap);
```

The `super(map)` invokes the `HashMap` constructor that copies all mappings of the argument map to the newly created map. From the docs:

> *Constructs a new HashMap with the same mappings as the specified Map.*